# Using a ui-router resolve to wait for a google map to load

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-promise, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to load a google map before loading the dashboard state.  Seems like the perfect use for a ui-router `resolve`.

Unfortunately, the `uiGmapIsReady` promise is never resolving.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
state('app.dashboard', {
  url: '/dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
  controller: 'dashCtrl',
  data: {
    authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
  },
  resolve: {
    getGoogleMap: function(MapService){

      return MapService.getMap();
    }
  }
})



.factory('MapService', function(uiGmapIsReady, $q) {

  var obj = {};

  //returns a promise that is resolved only after the google map object created by angular-google-maps is loaded
  obj.getMap = function(){

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    uiGmapIsReady.promise()
      .then(function(map){
        deferred.resolve(map[0].map);
      });

    return deferred.promise;

  };

return obj;
```

Comment: Think that I might've figured out my (simple) mistake.  The controller that was waiting on the resolve is also the controller that establishes the scope variables needed by angular-google-maps to draw the map.  That controller never gets called --> map never gets drawed -->  resolve never triggers --> controller never gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The controller that was waiting on the resolve was also the controller that establishes the scope variables needed by angular-google-maps to draw the map. That caused this:   resolve cause the controller to not get called --> map never gets drawn because it is waiting on the controller to set some scope objects--> resolve that is waiting for map to be drawn never triggers --> controller never gets called